# Word unscrambler in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string

Let's say I have the input string "Hello" I want to be able to retrieve these output words: hole, lol, eh, hell
All the output words letters should be contained in the input string.

How I should be able to achieve that? I've tried to use like:

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE word LIKE (%h%) OR (%e%) OR (%l%) OR (%l%) OR (%o%)
```

But this returns words such as: hi، loop,etc.. but I need the all the letters to be contained in the input string

Comment: I'd say that instead of OR you should use AND if you want that the string contains h AND e AND l AND o (in different order). But I don't see how lol and eh can be acceptable and hi or loop no

Comment: Because the 'p' and 'oo' in "loop" are not contained by the string "hello" where "hello" does not contain 'p' and contain only one 'o' and "lol" letters are contained in the string "hello". So basically all the output words letters should be contained in the input string

Comment: It should not have all the letters, but all of it's  letters should be contained in the input string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) pattern matching for this task. This will match all words that contain characters from the required set.

```
SELECT * 
FROM words 
WHERE word REGEXP ('[helo]+')
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iV84ahE9HsNhjMYUCusjK4/0).

**Note**: the `REGEXP` function is not case sensitive.

---

**EDIT**. Matching only the characters contained in the set of characters.

In this case you can look for words that do not match all the other characters:

```
SELECT * 
FROM words 
WHERE word NOT REGEXP ('[^helo]+')
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iV84ahE9HsNhjMYUCusjK4/1).

Comment: Thank you, but this would return also "helloworld", I need the all of the output letters to be contained in the input string where in "helloworld" the 'w', 'd' are not contained in 'hello'

Comment: Hello, I've noticed that this return words with more than one occurrence for a letter, for example: if i give it the string "doh" it will return the word: hood. Do you have any idea to stop the word from having multiple letters occurrences

Comment: The ugly but working solution would be to see if each of the letter of your pattern is contained inside the word, then check the length of the word: `WHERE (word LIKE '%d%') AND (word LIKE '%o%') AND (word LIKE '%h%') AND (LENGTH(word) = 3)`. Yet this solution wouldn't cover the case when you require a letter in the word to appear twice (for which you would require indices of each letter, something like this), though this becomes a way more complex problem. Is it possible some kind of narrowing by working on the original data?

Comment: One very complex solution would be counting the amount of single letters for each word as separate fields, but at this point maybe it wouldn't be worth the effort...

Comment: Thank you, but before we go to this kind of complex solutions, Is there any thing we can do with this Regex ( SELECT * 
FROM words 
WHERE word NOT REGEXP ('[^hello]+')) to make it accept one occurrence of each letter in the output words